# Does Islam claim that congenital deaf-blindness could never be cured by humans?

Tags: prophets, science, miracles

Salam,

Prophets were sent by God to guide humans. But it is ambiguous and unwise to believe what anyone says.

But what distinguished prophets from others ( for example magicians) was their **unchallenged** miracles. The miracles were distinct because they were divine and given directly by god ; such that no human things/tricks can defeat it ever. For example, Quran is miraculous because it claims that no book can be written ever guiding (and it's other features.) like it till the day of resurrection.

Hence, one should believe prophets because their miracles are unchallenged by humans; thus making them unambiguous; and hence one of key absolute proofs for submission to god.

**Question:**

One of miracles of Isa(Jesus) (peace be upon him) was to heal people with diseases which were from birth. For example, [congenital deafness/blindness](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/deafblindness/causes/#:%7E:text=Deafblindness%20from%20birth%20is%20known,%2C%20toxoplasmosis%20or%20cytomegalovirus%20(CMV)). So , **does Islam claims that humans will never be able to find cure of congenital deafness/blindness ; thus preserving the un-ambiguity of miracles of it's prophets ?**

Answer (score 1):

Miracles are only signs that indicate someone is a prophet of God. There is no special condition in all of them that states they can never be replicated with technology.

But, when they are done with technology or when they are done at a time when that is possible, there is nothing miraculous about them. What is miraculous is when a man does it without any technology or in a time when it is not possible.

If he does that, that is clear evidence he was given power from the supernatural.

Comment: If a miracle like thing can be done so easily by humans in future, who would count it as very supernatural than super-advanced than the people of their era , let go related to divine? Do you claim that all miracles of prophets can be replicated by humans in future ( except quran) ?

Comment: @An_Elephant The point of evidence in a miracle is that it breaks the normal flow of nature and a prophet shows this to prove God supports Him.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by superadvanced, but even if we used that word, the fact that someone has the ability to do something superadvanced while there is no natural possibility for it at the time shows a break in the normal flow of nature and proves he is sent by God.

Comment: *"there is no natural possibility"* . There are many ! One of them is time machine. Do you have a logical proof that can eliminate time machine used by advanced future humans  as a possibility?

Comment: I am not claiming that it is indeed the time machine. I am just saying that there are countless possibilities and it is not possible with the help of logic to determine the correct one.